# How to add migration details to its corresponding model in Rails 4

Tags: activerecord, rubygems, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations

I remember one of my colleagues did this but I don't remember how. Guess he used some gem or a rake task to achieve this.

Please share if you know how to do this.

Maybe even a gem that can add relevant associations automatically to the model file. This when we do rails g model.

Comment: This? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-generate

Comment: @D-side: can you tell me the command.. now i feel really silly asking this question, after working on rails for over 6 years.. thanks for being polite :)

Comment: Command `rails generate model Thing property:string entity:references` will create a model class `Thing` with migration for fields in database: a table `things` with columns (a string `property` and an integer `entity_id`) and create an index for `entity_id`. Associations are up to you, Rails will only try to fill in `belongs_to` (because it's the only thing it can guess, here it will output `belongs_to :entity`). Is that it?

Comment: Sorry this does not happens for me !! and I am using this format only :(

Comment: It's really unclear what you're asking. This is what **should** happen with default settings in an up-to-date environment (Rails 4.1, Ruby 2.1.3, older versions may likely work as well). If it doesn't, look for exact issues and error messages then post your findings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this gem:

https://github.com/ctran/annotate_models

Then run annotate from the terminal. It notes if the field is hstore or array type in case of postgresql. So it is very intelligent. Even myself made a commit to it ;)